# Initailizing nested dict with .fromkeys

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Hi I was wondering when creating a nested dictionary use the fromkeys method to created a nested dict does not work.

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[7,8,9,10,11]
zx=dict.fromkeys(x,dict.fromkeys(y,0))
```

It creates a nested dict but when you try to update it

zx[1][8]+=1

It updates all values for all outerkeys that have the key 8.

I was wondering why this happened when using this function to make a nested dict

Comment: That's because you associated all keys with the *same* value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you associated *all* keys of the outer dictionary with the *same* inner dictionary. You first constructed a dictionary with `dict.fromkeys(y,0)`, and then you associate that dictionary with all the keys with: `dict.fromkeys(x,...)`.

A way to construct the dictionary you want is for instance *dictionary comprehension*:

```
zx = {k: dict.fromkeys(y,0) for k in x}
```

Although this looks quite the same it is not: here, we will for *every* `k` in `x` evaluate `dict.fromkeys(y,0)` *again*. As a result, the constructed dictionaries will all he *equivalent*, but *not* the same object.

Now we obtain the expected:

```
>>> x=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> y=[7,8,9,10,11]
>>> zx = {k: dict.fromkeys(y,0) for k in x}
>>> zx
{1: {8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 7: 0}, 2: {8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 7: 0}, 3: {8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 7: 0}, 4: {8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 7: 0}, 5: {8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 7: 0}}
>>> zx[1][8]+=1
>>> zx
{1: {8: 1, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 7: 0}, 2: {8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 7: 0}, 3: {8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 7: 0}, 4: {8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 7: 0}, 5: {8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 7: 0}}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you get unhashable type list? So would I have to make the list tuples?

Comment: @user6656104: but the keys are not lists, the keys are *elements* of the list. Given these elements are hashable (like ints, strings, etc.) then there is no problem.